# Oracle APEX hosting in IIS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm unable to deploy oracle apex in Windows 10 IIS , can you tell me how to deploy oracle apex pages in iis ( Internet Information Services )

Answer (score 2):

You need a java web container (TomCat, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc) to deploy ORDS which will connect to your database that is running APEX. I'm not sure if you can deploy `.war` files in IIS. If you can, then you should be good to go and deploy the `ords.war` within it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you can run the ords.war as a [standalone application](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37099_01/doc.20/e25066/install.htm#AELIG7022) where it will use it's internal Jetty server and use IIS Application Request Routing to create a reverse proxy connection to it.